# TypeError: Не удается прочитать свойство объекта undefined

Tags: telegram-bot, google-apps-script

Телеграм бот по вебхуку связан с гугл скриптом

```
function doPost(e){
  var contents = JSON.parse(e.postData.contents);
  GmailApp.sendEmail("######@gmail.com", "Telegram Bot Update", JSON.stringify(e.postData.contents,null,4));
  var text = contents.message.text;
  var id = contents.message.from.id;
  var name = contents.message.from.first_name + " " + contents.message.from.last_name;
  sendText(id, "Hi, " + name);
}
```

Код должен отправить на мой мейл сообщение  с информацией о о сообщении в боте, а потом ответить на него.

При получении ботом сообщения скрипт лишь отправляет мейл, а ответа нет. При запуске отдельно функции вылетает с данной ошибкой.

> TypeError: Не удается прочитать свойство "postData" объекта undefined.

Подскажите, как правильно передавать е в функцию, чтобы она была определена?

Comment: Вы, для начала, покажите как сейчас `e` в `doPost` передаёте.

Comment: Как я понимаю, в нее должны сохраняться данные из сообщения, которое посылается по вебхуку, @Suvitruf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используйте для отладки что-то вроде

```
function doPost(e) {
  try {
    var contents = JSON.parse(e.postData.contents);
    sendMessage(contents);
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(e, contents, err);
  }
}
```

Тогда вы будете хотябы понимать, в каком месте у вас ошибка.

Что касается сути вопроса, то "TypeError: Не удается прочитать свойство объекта undefined" возникает потому, что вы не передаете в `doPost(e)` при ручном запуске. В таком случае, понятно, что `e === undefined`.

Для отладки такого кода вам необходимо реализовать вручную объект `e` и передавать его через тестовую функцию

```
function tDoPost() {
  var telegaSays = {
    "postData": {
      "update_id": 000,
      "message": {
        "chat": {
          "first_name": "Alexander",
          "id": 000,
          "last_name": "Ivanov",
          "type": "private",
          "username": "oshliaer"
        },
        "date": 000,
        "from": {
          "first_name": "Alexander",
          "id": 000,
          "is_bot": false,
          "language_code": "en",
          "last_name": "Ivanov",
          "username": "oshliaer"
        },
        "message_id": 000,
        "text": "тест"
      }
    }
  };
  doPost(telegaSays);
}
```

Важно. Ваш скрипт должен быть опубликован от вашего имени для всех и анонимусов. Причем после каждой правки вы обязаны публиковать новую версию.

Comment: С помощью тестовой функции проверил и все заработало, ошибка была в том, что для функции sendText я не установил параметры `(id, text)` и изменил id на указанный Вами. Теперь бот все обрабатывает, отвечает в ЛС и пишет на имейл. Спасибо

Comment: А как вы отправляете ответ на `contents.message.from.id` ? У меня так не работает. Ок, разобрался. При приватном ответе эти `id` совпадают.

Comment: У меня работает и `from`, и `chat`, но это потому что через лс и они одинаковые, я же просто string отправляю в sendText, он не должен видеть разницы. Если буду вносить бота в группы, там уже должна быть разница в ответе в группе/личке определенного человека.